# Creating files in specific folders in Drive using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a Google Document (and would be useful for any other type of file) in a specific folder in Drive. I have consulted previous questions here on stack overflow, but cannot get my results. I have tried two different ways:

```
function createDoc(){

  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1SsLunZh5sn5HDGkcCcTBoXkvDdc70J4g');
  var resource = {
    title: "New Test Doc",
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS,
    parents: [{ id: destFolder }]
  }

  Logger.log(destFolder);

  var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource);
  var fileId = fileJson.id;

  Logger.log(fileId);

}
```

I've got the Advanced Drive API activated, but I get an error message stating:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: File not found: Udemy GAS Complete Course (line 25, file "Code")

I've also tried this:

```
function createDoc2(){

  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1SsLunZh5sn5HDGkcCcTBoXkvDdc70J4g');
  var newDoc = DriveApp.createFile("New Test Doc", "", MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);

}
```

But I get an error stating:
Exception: Invalid argument: file.contentType (line 35, file "Code")

Would very much appreciate some insight. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work for you.  I didn't test it.  I just found that you didn't include the getId() method in id: key for the resource.

```
function createDoc(){
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderId');
  var resource = {"title": "New Test Doc",mimeType:MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS,parents: [{id:destFolder.getId() }]}
  var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource);
  var fileId = fileJson.id;
}
```

If this doesn't work let me know I'll be glad to take a better look at it.

Comment: This did it @Cooper  I figured it must have been something small slipping. I am very new to all of this. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

@Cooper My script is bound to a spreadsheet creating a form in the same directory as the spreadsheet. It works fine in a folder on my drive but gets the error when run from a shared drive. (educational account)

```
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(ssId);
  console.info('file = ' + file);
  let folders = file.getParents(); 
  let parFldr, parFldrId;
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let parFldr = folders.next();
    console.log('folder Name(): ', parFldr.getName() );
    parFldrId = parFldr.getId();
    console.log('folder Id(): ', parFldrId );
    console.log('folder Url(): ', parFldr.getUrl() );
  }

  const fileResource = {
    title: qTitle,
    description :qDesc,
    confirmationMessage:qConfMsg,
    collectsEmail:true,    // this worked ! ! ! ! !
    requireLogin:true,     // worked limited to school district
//    isQuiz:false,   // did not set - did it in another ways
    "parents": [{'id':parFldrId}],  
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.form'
  };

  let dummyForm = Drive.Files.insert(fileResource);
  let newForm = FormApp.openById(dummyForm.id);
```

console.log

```
file = Preposition Quizzes (Form from SS)
folder Name():  Grammar
folder Id():  1rpezlYt6xWJBIOtYinF9_bAGd46y9-Er
folder Url():  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rpezlYt6xWJBIOtYinF9_bAGd46y9-Er
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: File not found: 1rpezlYt6xWJBIOtYinF9_bAGd46y9-Er
```

[image: share permissions]
[image: drive API turned on under Advanced Services]

I do not see the difference between my code and your solution. Am I missing something or is there a problem with working on a shared drive?  Thanks.  I know I am not supposed to publish my own question but I think it is useful to keep this thread together.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to create the file in a shared drive, you have to add the `supportsAllDrives` parameters.

Taking the chosen answer as example:

```
function createDoc(){
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderId');
  var resource = {"title": "New Test Doc",mimeType:MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS,parents: [{id:destFolder.getId() }]}
  var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource, null, {supportsAllDrives: true});
  var fileId = fileJson.id;
}
```